# Write multiple topics in Kafka by Flink dynamically Exception handling

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I am currently reading data from a single kafka topic and writing to dynamic topic based on data itself. I have implemented the following code (which is dynamically selecting topic based on accountId of data) and it working just fine :

```scala
class KeyedEnrichableEventSerializationSchema(schemaRegistryUrl: String)
    extends KafkaSerializationSchema[KeyedEnrichableEvent]
    with KafkaContextAware[KeyedEnrichableEvent] {
  private val enrichableEventClass = classOf[EnrichableEvent]
  private val enrichableEventSerialization: AvroSerializationSchema[EnrichableEvent] =
    ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema.forSpecific(enrichableEventClass, enrichableEventClass.getCanonicalName, schemaRegistryUrl)

  override def serialize(element: KeyedEnrichableEvent, timestamp: lang.Long): ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] =
    new ProducerRecord("trackingevents."+element.value.getEventMetadata.getAccountId, element.key, enrichableEventSerialization.serialize(element.value))

  override def getTargetTopic(element: KeyedEnrichableEvent): String = "trackingevents."+element.value.getEventMetadata.getAccountId
```

The problem/concern is, if the topic does not exist, i am having an exception in JobManager UI about the topic not present and whole processing is halted until I create the topic. May be this is recommended behaviour but is there any alternate like maybe we can put the data in different topic and resume processing instead of stopping whole processing. Or at least is there any notification mechanism available in flink which notifies immediately that the processing is halted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest solution in this case is to enable autocreation of topics in Kafka, so that problem is solved totally.

However, if for some reason it's impossible to be done in Your case, the simplest solution IMHO would be to create a `ProcessFunction`, which would keep a connection to Kafka using `KafkaConsumer` or `AdminClient` and periodically check if the topic that would be used for given message exists. You could then whether push the data to sideOutput or try to create topics that are missing.